# JPA : relation with other column than id

Tags: java, jpa

When I do a relation one to one with to entities, JPA use the id to register the target ; but I should want an other column. How is possible ?

For instance I have two entities :

```
@Entity
public class Target
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String id;

  @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
  private String code;

 // and so on 
}
```

That's make a table with columns ID and CODE.

A second entity with a link to Coder :

```
@Entity
public class ToTarget
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String id;

 private Target targeted;

 // and so on 
}
```

That's make a table with column ID and TARGET_ID. In TARGET_ID I have some id from column ID in table Target.

All is good, but I should want, in TARGET_ID, some code value from table Coder. How is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `referencedColumnName` attribute of the `@JoinColumn` annotation. I'm not sure this is supported by the standard though. It might work in some implementations, and not in others.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association for Hibernate, and http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.1.0/apache-openjpa-2.1.0/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins for OpenJPA.

Comment: I use eclipse link. Unfortunately it says : "The reference column name mapped on the element does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference". I write on the target : `Column(unique=true, nullable=false) private String code;` and on the src `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="code") private Target target;`.

Comment: Thanks, I find another "solution". That's help me to know this way is difficult.

Comment: @Istao Could you post your solution?

Comment: I wrote a handler, outside JPA, wich translate one id into another id. It was for a swing model.